# Netbeans Java complaining about final variable not being initialised

Tags: java, netbeans

Consider this code:

```
final MyClass myObject;
try {
    myObject = new MyClass(...)
} catch (MyClassException){
    // terminate
    System.exit(1);
}

myObject.doSomething();
```

The problem is that the Netbeans editor / parser thinks that `.doSomething()` could be called on an unitialised object which, of course, is not the case.

Is there an normal / standard pattern for circumventing this? I could call into a function but would rather not do that. I'd also rather not enclose the whole block in the try catch block since nothing else throws `MyClassException`

I'm not (yet ;-) ) an expert on Java grammar and patterns so am hope I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You initialize your object in `try` block, which may throw exception, leaving object uninitialized.

In your `catch` block, you stop your program, but `System.exit(1)` does not stop method execution, instead, it [terminates currently running JVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) - and for compiler it's just another method you call if an exception is thrown.

`return` actually stops method execution - so no code beyond `return;` is reached.
You can modify your `catch` block as following:

```
catch (MyClassException){
    // terminate
    System.exit(1);
    return;
}
```

Compiler won't complain about `myObject` not being initialized this way.

**EDIT**

NB: if you put `myObject.doSomething();` in `finally` block compiler WILL complain, since `finally` is executed even after `return`.

```
finally {
    // compiler error
    myObject.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: `throw new Error();` or similar would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

The case is that outside the try/catch block you try to call a method on a possibly not instantiated object. That is because the try/catch block may throw exceptions so the object is not created, therefore in this case you will not have an object when you try to call the `doSomething()` method on it.

If you include the method call in the try/catch block, it will work.

You can find related information here:
[Java Tutorials: Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Not quite because if the object is not created, I terminate with System.exit(1). Drastic I know.

Comment: And what if e.g. there is an exception in the catch block? :-)

Comment: @Bathsheba what if an exception occurs within the `catch` block? You know, you could run out of memory while trying to die.

Comment: If an exception is caused within the catch block, than myObject.doSomething() will not be reached at all

Answer (score 1):

> Netbeans editor / parser thinks that .doSomething() could be called on an unitialised object which, of course, is not the case.

You are wrong here. You are in fact **trying** to initialize the variable. The compiler doesn't "trust" in the initialization and the reason is simple: it **could** throw an exception, which you could catch **but not throw** a new `RuntimeException()` or make a `System.exit(1)`. For example:

```
try {
    myObject = new MyClass(...)
} catch (MyClassException e){
    // hey I catch this but do nothing lmao yolo
    e.printStackTrace();
}

myObject.doSomething();
```

you could catch the exception, print the stacktrace and continue the program, and the consequence would be a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: But there is System.exit in the exception block. So it means of there is an exception , jvm will not reach the .doSomething call.

Comment: But JVM compiler doesn't work that way. It doesn't trust in what it's inside the try-catch clause, no matter what you put in there. You can't tell java "hey, trust me, there won't be any issue, take a look, I put a system.exit(1) in there!"

Comment: I know, why compiler cannot be improved for a scenario when JVM itself is getting terminated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can do:

```
final MyClass myObject;
{
    MyClass local = null;
    try {
        local = new MyClass(...)
    } catch (MyClassException){
        // terminate
        System.exit(1);
    }
    myObject = local;
}

myObject.doSomething();
```

Comment: You gonna upvote it? Must be a badge for that ;-) Seriously though I don't like this pattern and it circumvents points in other answers.

Comment: Moving the declaration into the try block is best. but in the specific example you gave, where there is no finally block accessing myObject, you will never get null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the `final` variables and members is to always be initialized. Although your code will never call `doSomething`, it will leave the final field undefined. This becomes an issue if you add a `finally` clause to the try-catch block - you may enter the `finally` clause when exception occurs and the `myObject` will not be available, which the compiler must avoid.

```
final MyClass myObject;
try {
    myObject = new MyClass(...); // constructor may throw exception
} catch (MyClassException){
    // terminate
    System.exit(1);
} finally {
    // what does myObject point to now, if the constructor threw exception?
}

myObject.doSomething();
```

A quick solution is to move the `doSomething` call in the try block:

```
final MyClass myObject;
try {
    myObject = new MyClass(...);
    myObject.doSomething();
} catch (MyClassException){
    // terminate
    System.exit(1);
}
```

This should work fine as long as `doSomething` does not also throw a `MyClassException`. If it throws such exception, you probably need to differentiate the case whether it came from the constructor or the method (if of course this matters to your logic).

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the Netbeans editor / parser thinks that .doSomething() could be called on an unitialised object which, of course, is not the case.

It **is** the case: nothing prevents you from using a `SecurityManager` which will forbid `System.exit()` from exiting the JVM. In that situation, the next statement **could** be executed.

From a Java grammar perspective, the compiler needs to prove that `myObject` is *definitely assigned* when you call `myObject.doSomething();`.

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.2.13) specifies the situations in which this can be done. In particular, the only statements that can be used to determine that the next instruction(s) will not be executed are `break`, `continue`, `return`, and `throw`. So the compiler is not allowed to consider that `System.exit(1);` will prevent the next statement from being executed.

Comment: As a point of pedantry, the `SecurityManager` could only prevent the exit by throwing an (any) exception (or not returning).